pnpm align dependency versions across packages in monorepo
I'm building an extension for Prisma, and I've put two workspaces into a monorepo, one for the package itself, and one for development testing:
/package.json
/pnpm-workspace.yaml
/package/package.json
/dev-test/package.json

In both the package itself and the test workspace, I have prisma as a dev dependency. In the package itself, I have @prisma/client as a peer dependency, and as a full dependency in the test space.
The issue I'm facing is, it often occurs that it will install a different patch version of the client than of the main prisma module. For example, right now it's installing prisma@5.16.1 and @prisma/client@5.16.0. This can, and does, result in problems, so the question is, how do I get pnpm to make sure they stay in sync?
Here are the relevant sections of the package.json files:
# file=/package.json
# i.e., nothing to do with prisma or @prisma/client in the root package.json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@changesets/changelog-github": "^0.5.0",
    "@changesets/cli": "^2.27.6"
  },
}

# file=/package/package.json
{
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.14.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prisma": "^5.14.0",
  }
}

# file=/dev-test/package.json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@prisma/client": "^5.14.0",
        "prisma-extension-pgvector": "workspace:^"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "prisma": "^5.14.0"
    }
}

This Q&A are slightly different, because they're trying to sync the same package version in different workspaces, rather than sync versions between different packages. Nevertheless, it pointed me at overrides as a potential solution, but I can't get that to work.
I tried using
    "pnpm": {
      "overrides": {
          "@prisma/client": "$prisma"
      }
    }

to force @prisma/client to use the same version as prisma, but if I put it in dev-test/package.json, it complains

WARN  The field "pnpm" was found in dev-test/package.json. This will not take effect. You should configure "pnpm" at the root of the workspace instead.

Whereas, if I do as suggested and put it in the root of the workspace, it complains

ERR_PNPM_CANNOT_RESOLVE_OVERRIDE_VERSION  Cannot resolve version $prisma in overrides. The direct dependencies don't have dependency "prisma".

Ideas? What else can I try?

Have you found any solution?

Unfortunately, no. I've just ended up manually forcing the 3rd digit in the test package whenever the main package updates.
